# Using icons in GitHub issue form templates

Tags: github, github-issues

I'm currently trying to set up an issue form for my GitHub repo. I was wondering if it is possible to embed an svg icon (e.g. from Font Awesome) in one of the boxes.

For example:

```yaml
body:
  - type: dropdown
    attributes:
      label: Thing
      options:
        - Option 1
        - Option 2 (but with dragon) <i class="fa-solid fa-dragon"></i>
        - Option 3 (with biohazard danger) <i class="fa-solid fa-biohazard"></i>
```

I'm guessing that the above won't work, but you get the idea. Is there a way to embed a vector icon in a form?